# Visual studio 2013: format all the code

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a large heterogeneously formatted C++ solution and I don't want to press <kbd>ctrl+E</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl+D</kbd> in all existing source files.

How can I make this automatically?

Comment: make a macros! open all files -> reformat -> save

Comment: No more macros in VS2013.